is there function to make project open fullscreen mode with only an exit button (X) and a minimize button (-)?
my code is:
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


def minimize_window():
    root2.iconify()

def exit_fullscreen():
    root2.destroy()    

def new_root():
    global root2, time_label
    root2 = Tk()
    root2.title("MONEY")
    root2.geometry('1500x700')
    
    # Open the window in fullscreen mode
    root2.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root2.resizable(False, False)
    
    # Create an exit button (X)
    exit_button = Button(root2, text="X", font="ar 15 bold", command=exit_fullscreen, bg='red', fg='white')
    exit_button.place(x=1450, y=10)  # Position in the top right corner
    
    # Create a minimize button (-)
    minimize_button = Button(root2, text="-", font="ar 15 bold", command=minimize_window, bg='gray', fg='white')
    minimize_button.place(x=1400, y=10)  # Position next to the exit button
    

root2.mainloop()

is there any thing wroge because when i run it i got what i want
1- the full screen mode
2- the 2 buttons
but
the buttons not lie what i want, i want it stay in the same place for it without change

Aside: why are you using globals? It seems to me that root2.inconify and root2.destroy don't need wrappers at all.

Anyways, what precisely about this code is insufficient? Is it that you want the buttons to be in the top right corner? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Study how relx and anchor options of place() work.

@Anerdw about your first comment i need the global because this is a small part of my full project so there is allot of codes and second i guess maybe you understand what i i want (every program you open it have 3 buttons in the top right side wech is (-) minimize (x) close and between them the square that control the maximize ) but i
want to make the program when i run it have only(-) and (x) and it open directly full screen mode and you  didn't give me my answer (-_-)

@acw1668 the things that you suggest to study it is about what i want ??
jus in case read my replay comment for the second guy i explain more maybe you will know what i want exactly

Yes, if you understand how those options of place() work, then you can achieve what you want.
